# How to increase the life of the application key?

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

How to increase the life of the application key? The default is `one hour`

> {"access_token":"ya29.GlubBHRrSI1rJcFqTllIzCqWSd48E8GX9xTgcDqaR7JVhHzxABdV2Z-0T256tqroQipuvZYbIPwcYvSdyCrnWDlQLJvhzt0cOalYmBJ2nwUOo734uD4pnQOr5pshK","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":**3600**,"created":1501687024}

Comment: which technology are you using? php or .net ??

Comment: hello! php technology

Comment: you not receive `refresh_token` from the response?

Comment: I have only CLIENT_SECRET and CREDENTIALS.

Comment: use `refresh_token` to get new `access_token` when it expired. Maybe the `CREDENTIALS` is your refresh_token

Answer (score 1):

Access tokens have only a lifespan of 1 hour, after that, you'll be needing refresh tokens. You can set them in PHP by using `client->setAccessType("offline");`

For more info about refresh tokens, you can read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953983/do-google-refresh-tokens-expire).

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996918/google-oauth2-access-token-expires-in-1-hour-i-want-to-make-it-1-day) has PHP implementations that might be of help as well.